# How to derive until I arrive at DNF

Tags: computer-science, boolean-algebra

Hello I have this Boolean formula:1...   (¬P ∨ Q) ∧ (¬Q ∨ R) ∧ (¬R ∨ S) ∧ (¬S ∨ P) ∧ M ∧ ¬N

I separated this into 5 pieces and I wrote the truth table, then from the truth table I found that DNF of this formula is:

2... ((¬P ∨ Q) ∧ (¬Q ∨ R) ∧ (¬R ∨ S) ∧ (¬S ∨ P) ∧ ¬M ∧ N ) ∨ ((P ∨ Q) ∧ (Q ∨ R) ∧ (R ∨ S) ∧ (S ∨ P) ∧ M ∧ N)

But we have to been told to arrive to this form of DNF:

3... (M ∧ ¬N ∧ ¬P ∧ ¬Q ∧ ¬R ∧ ¬S) ∨ (M ∧ ¬N ∧ ¬P ∧ R ∧ S) ∨ (M ∧ ¬N ∧ Q ∧ R ∧ S)

Now I took the formula 2... and I did this operation, but I do not know how to further derive in oder to arrive to formula 3...

Here is whay I did:

((¬P + Q) * (¬Q + R) * (¬R + S) * (¬S + P) * (¬M + N ) + ((P + Q) * (Q + R) * (R + S) * (S + P) * M * N)

((¬P¬Q + ¬PR + Q¬Q + QR) * (¬R¬S + ¬RP + S¬S + SP) * ¬M *N)  + ((PQ + PR + QQ + QR) * (RS + RP +SS + SP) * M * N)

Now I know that Q¬Q = 0, S¬S = 0, QQ =Q and SS=S, then I substitute these in:

((¬P¬Q + ¬PR + QR) * (¬R¬S + ¬RP + SP) * ¬M *N)  + ((PQ + PR + Q + QR) * (RS + RP +S  + SP) * M * N)

But here I do not know how to derive this more in order to arrive at 3...

Can someone guide me how to actually arrive there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with the 'answer' given in 3, as 3. would be true if $Q$, $R$, $S$, and $M$ are true, and $P$ and $N$ are false (for it would make the third disjunct true), but the original statement is false in that case, as the conjunct $\neg S \lor P$ would be false. So 3. is not equivalent to 1.

Here's what I get (I'll use $P'$ for $\neg P$):

$$(P' + Q)(Q' + R)(R' + S)(S' + P)=$$

$$P'Q'R'S'+P'Q'R'P+P'Q'SS'+P'Q'SP+P'RR'S'+P'RR'P+P'RSS'+P'RSP+
QQ'R'S'+QQ'R'P+QQ'SS'+QQ'SP+QRR'S'+QRR'P+QRSS'+QRSP$$

Given $PP'=0$, $P0=0$, and $P+0=P$, we can eliminate any term that contains some atomic claim and its complement, and thus we get:

$$P'Q'R'S'+P'Q'R'P+P'Q'SS'+P'Q'SP+P'RR'S'+P'RR'P+P'RSS'+P'RSP+
QQ'R'S'+QQ'R'P+QQ'SS'+QQ'SP+QRR'S'+QRR'P+QRSS'+QRSP=$$

$$P'Q'R'S'+QRSP$$

(which makes sense if you look at those four original terms:  as soon as you set one of $P$, $Q$, $R$, or $S$ to true to satisfy one of the terms, you are forced to chain through and set them all to true. Likewise, once you set one of the m to false, you'll have to set all of them to false. So there are indeed only two ways to satisfy this: either all true or all false)

Plugging that into the original expression, we thus get:

$$(P' + Q)(Q' + R)(R' + S)(S' + P)MN'=$$

$$(P'Q'R'S'+PQRS)MN'=$$

$$P'Q'R'S'MN'+PQRSMN'$$

Comment: I just checked the DNF of formula 1... in the Wolfram Alpha DNF Caclulator and its giving me the formula 3..  !!, but in the other hand your statement makes sense hah

Comment: @Dan Hmm, Call me biased, but I trust my reasoning better than Wolfram alpha! :). Can you maybe post the link to that Wolfrm Alph calculation in your question?

Comment: @Dan OK, I just enteeed the statement into Wolfram Alpha as well ... and it came up exactly with *my* answer! Are you sure you're entering the formula correctly?

Comment: First, my apologies for the Wolfram Alpha since I wrote that differently there by mistake! and another thing which I want to ask, you went from Formula 1.. directly to its DNF, right? (without using my Formula 2.. which I got from the truth table)

Comment: @Dan Correct!  In fact, I had not yet looked at your 2. and now see that that one is also not equivalent to 1,  ... did you maybe enter 2. Into Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: No I dont, I entered 1 in wolfram alpha but instead of (¬S ∨ P) I entered (¬S ∨ R), OMG my 2... is not equivalent to 1 ????, I found 2... by the truth table, can I send to  you how I arrive at 2.. so you can check that out ?

Comment: @Dan If you post it (maybe as a picture in your answer) I'd be happy to check it.  But I can immediately tell it's not equiavelent to 1.  For 1 to be true you *definitely* need M true and N false .... and this is the case in neither of your two disjuncts of 2.

Comment: I was writing in the paper and while writing I realised my mistake, but now by the truth table, my DNF is just the formula 1.. which is not okay, right?. I'm very confused at this point.

Comment: Here is my Truth Table to DNF thing https://ibb.co/jPP8MR

Comment: @Dan Your truth-table for the $M \land \neg N$ is incorrect: it should only have a $1$ for when $M=1$ and $N=0$ ... which gets you back to $M \land \neg N$!  Also note that your eventual result is in CNF, not DNF.  If you want DNF, you need to construct the *combined* truth-table for the one large statement ... which will have $64$ rows!

Comment: Okay, how can I find how many interpretations of the 6 variables satisfy the formula and how to proof this? (w/o using 64 row table)

Comment: @Dan  By doing what I did: use Boolean algebra to transform it into DNF, and making it as simple as possible. So, my answer shows there are exactly 2 interpretations.

Comment: So basically what u did is both of them right?, you used Boolean algebra to reduce the expression, and then you found out that there are only 2 possible ways for which this expression is going to be true, and then you wrote the DNF. If this is correct then I have one last question, how do I find the CNF first, and then derive DNF from CNF?

Comment: @Dan Well, I used Boolean Algebra, and when I was done it was in what is called 'canonical' DNF .. this is where each term refers to each variable (this is called a 'minterm') and, as such, represents a specific interpretation. So, since I ended up with two such terms, I knew there were two interpretations. And I did not have to rewrite it in DNF since it is *already* in DNF.  For finding CNF .. well, 1. is already in CNF, as it is a conjunction of disjunctions of literals. For going from CNF to DNF: keep distributing $\land$ over $\lor$.

Comment: @Dan  Some more on CNF to DNF:  You probably know the FOIL principle from algebra: $(a + b)(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd$. That works exactly the same way in boolean algebra. And, it generalizes to having multiple terms; you just have to find all possible combinations where you pick one disjunct from each conjunct .. and that's exactly what I did at the beginning of my Answer: with $4$ conjuncts, each having $2$ disjuncts, you get the $2^4=16$ possible combinations as shown.